# displaying image in gridview column

Tags: asp.net

I have image in the image folder and in my oracle database I have a column with the name IMG which has the name of

the image like  ab.jpg

I have another column with name IMG1 which is storing the whole url  like  images/ab.jpg

I can see all the values of my database table in my dataset as well including IMG column and IMG1 column

In my aspx file I wrote code

but it is not displaying anything, however aspx page is working fine, it is showing a field but no image and it is blank, same is

the case with IMG1 column as well

Why is it so?  What is wrong that I am doing?

I dont want to store image in database, so i store it in the folder

What method should i adopt to make it work?

**Update**

thats my code

```
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField= "DD" HtmlEncode="false" HeaderStyle-BorderColor="green" 
                HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="Arial" 
                HeaderStyle-Width="100%" HeaderStyle-Wrap="true" HeaderText="HEAD" 
                ItemStyle-Width="100%" >
                <ItemStyle BorderColor="green" HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="true" />
            </asp:BoundField>

<asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/images/ab.jpg" runat="server" />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

<asp:BoundField DataField="CC" HeaderText="SHEET" />

 </Columns>
```

If I look at design section it is giving me  image sign with a cross but not showing the actual image

location of image is

I have folder A and there I have sub folder images and mywebpage
so both mywebpage and images folder is in folder A

I have used paths as ~/images/ab.jpg and ~A/images/ab.jpg and in both cases it does not work

Method below does not work either

Using Oracle database, which is showing image url columns on dataset and even on grid as mentioned in my last post

What wrong am I doing?

Any solution?

Comment: Are you storing the images in a folder INSIDE of your app?

Comment: Please just edit your question to provide additional information.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't share your code but you can use [ImageField of GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479350.aspx) and set the DataImageUrlField to your image url.

You can alternatively go with TemplateField if you want more control over manipulation of url.

Sharing your code will have if the above doesn't meet your need.

**Edit 1:**

Since your page and images folder are in same folder try: **ImageUrl="images/ab.jpg"**

Although **ImageUr"~/A/images/ab.jpg"** should have worked.

Also to point sometimes the images might not appear in DesignView, so did you try opening your page in browser?